# Variant type mismatch at run time

Tags: vba, excel, com, ole

I am trying to automate *Bentley Microstation* from Excel using runtime objects without project References for a proof of concept.

```
Sub MSFromXlRuntime()

    Dim MS As Object
    Dim DesignFile As Object
    Dim Line As Object
    Dim startPoint As Variant
    Dim endPoint As Variant

    Set MS = CreateObject("MicroStationDGN.Application")
    MS.Visible = 1

    Set DesignFile = 
    MS.OpenDesignFile("C:\mydgn.dgn", False)

    startPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(2#, 2#, 0#)
    endPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(4#, 4#, 0#)

    Set Line = MS.CreateLineElement2(Nothing, startPoint, endPoint)

    MS.ActiveModelReference.AddElement Line

End Sub
```

The above code generates a `Run time Error '13' Type Mismatch`on line

```
Set Line = MS.CreateLineElement2(Nothing, startPoint, endPoint)
```

In the local window the type of the variables `startPoint` and `endPoint` appear as `Variant/Point3d` which is what the `CreateLineElement2()` function expects.
How can this be fixed?

**last attempt following comments**
Redefining the user datatype Point3d also gives an error as below. The Error in this case is :

> Compile error:
>   Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late bound functions

```
Type myPoint3d
X As Double
Y As Double
Z As Double
End Type

Sub MSFromXlRuntime()

Dim MS As Object
Dim DesignFile As Object
Dim Line As Object
Dim startPoint As myPoint3d
Dim endPoint As myPoint3d

Set MS = CreateObject("MicroStationDGN.Application")
MS.Visible = 1

Set DesignFile = MS.OpenDesignFile("C:\mydgn.dgn", False)

startPoint.X = 2#: startPoint.Y = 2#: startPoint.Z = 0#
endPoint.X = 4#: endPoint.Y = 4#: endPoint.Z = 0#

Set Line = MS.CreateLineElement2(Nothing, startPoint, endPoint)

MS.ActiveModelReference.AddElement Line

End Sub
```

I think maybe what I am trying is just not possible in VBA. I should stick to importing project references the usual way.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: As in [this article](https://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/archived-microstation-v8i-vba-forum/77528/create-new-element-and-add), how about casting the AddElement parameter with MicroStationDGN._Element?
Then, perhaps as in [this article](https://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/archived-microstation-v8i-programming-forum/64935/exception-with-createlineelement1-exception-in-vb-net), Redraw may not be necessary.

Comment: I had to edit my post which was misleading it's the Point3d elements that generate the error in CreateLineElement2(). I have tried casting with `(MicrostationDGN._Point3d)startPoint` as recommended but it does not seem to be valid VBA syntax. What is the proper dynamic cast syntax in VBA?

Comment: Are you sure it is the Point3d elements that are giving the type mismatch?  There is another parameter (the `Nothing`) that might also be the culprit.  Is `CreateLineElement2` expecting that first parameter to be an object such as `Nothing` or is it expecting a `Null`?

Comment: Probably this [MicroStation VBA Tips # Objects & User-Defined Types](http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/V8/MVBA/MVBA-Tips.htm#ObjectsAndUDTs) is the explanation of the cause and answer of your problem.

Comment: I tried with both Nothing and Null and both give the same error. Nothing works fine when the Dim are strongly typed.

Comment: I tried defining my own structure but it just gives a different error.